# Get full queue name from dispatcher RabbitMq

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I dispatch a message into queue:

```
using (var dispatcher = new Dispatcher<Scheduler.Queue.Contract.JobMessage>(new QueueConnectionInfo(_connectionSettings)))
{
    dispatcher.Dispatch(jobMessage.ToContract(), routingKey);
}
```

In case when I create consumer, I can easy get queue name: `consumer.QueueName`

How can I get full name of queue (like "Queue.{someComponent}.{someRoute}"), in which message was dispatched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot , since the Pub Sub pattern does warrants the publisher to know who all are the subscribers . The publisher only knows the exchange that it is publishing to and the exchange does the further bifurcation based on the queue bindings and respective routing keys.

However for troubleshooting RabbitMQ does provides you with a plugin ( which is not recommended for productions since it is resource heavy ) , the plugin is the [Firehose](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) plugin and it also comes with a UI which gives us the full trace from publish to all the queues that the message is routed it.